# How to keep the default variables in a Spring boot error controller

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have the following `error.html` page defined:

```
<div><b>Path:</b> <span th:text="${path}" /></div>
<div><b>Status:</b> <span th:text="${status}" /></div>
<div><b>Message:</b>  <span th:text="${message}" /></div>
```

However, when I create a custom error controller I 'lose' these variables:

```
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

  @RequestMapping("/error")
  public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
       return "error";
   }
}
```

How would I re-gain access to those variables that are usually defined in the default `error.html` template?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone more experienced can give a better answer, but here is the only way I figured out how to do it:

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Exception ex) {

    Object path = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
    Object status = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
    Object message = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message");

    model.addAttribute("path", path);
    model.addAttribute("status", status);
    model.addAttribute("message", message);

    return "error";
}
```

In other words, you have to  re-define all the variables that you would normally get without having written the new controller.